# How to upload videos and play in Drupal 7?

Tags: media, files

I am trying to upload custom *video* files to *Drupal site* and play the video. I have custom videos which are to be uploaded to posts.

Here I am not using any *YouTube* embedded links, instead I want to upload my own videos into my posts.

I also have installed the [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module and the *JWplayer* but I don't know how to configure the module to upload *videos* in my posts and play those videos.

I am a newbie to *Drupal*. Can anyone help me to configure this?

Comment: The most of modules contains file README.txt
You can check it to take some info about configuration and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/media) about the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module.

There is another [Drupal Video Setup Using Media and Media Youtube](http://gleamly.com/article/setup-video-your-drupal-website-using-media-and-mediayoutube)
 tutorial about using the [Media] and [Media Youtube](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_youtube) modules in a Drupal site.

If still you can't get it to work, then you can also check the tutorial [Post YouTube Videos with Media + Media: YouTube](https://www.drupal.org/node/1407140) (from Drupal's Post Installation forum).

Now choice is up to you in which you feel easy.

Answer (score 1):

You need a module like [Video](https://www.drupal.org/project/video). You can upload and also transcode videos with it. The module adds a new field type, Video, which can be used to upload and view videos. [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2281571) you can see how to install and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, The tutorial about "[Uploading Video Files in Drupal](http://en.flossmanuals.net/video-hosting-guide-t/uploading-video-files-in-drupal/)" worked for me. Here is part of what it is about (quote from that link):

> If we want a simple approach to uploading and playing our videos inside an HTML5 player, we can use the built-in File field provided in the Drupal core to hold our uploaded video and an added module to provide a player.

Basically what this tutorial explains is this:

- Add a field of the 'File' field type to a content type.
- Use the [Media Element](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediaelement) module.

Head over to the tutorial for more details if needed.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thanks for that... but i am still a newbie to drupal... i love learning things like this... cheers :)

Comment: I'm still a Drupal newbie too (compared to "Dries") ... If you want to learn, then make sure to also visit the "tour" around here (link within help, upper right). Looking at your profile it shows you have never done so. Make sure to also visit http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ... Good luck!

Comment: I slightly (?!?!) expanded your answer, mostly by reformatting it a bit, and adding some details about that link. Please review / correct / expand where you think it is appropriate. If you like it, please try to remember it in future answers, ok? Ps: curious if it will help to get your -1 vote removed again ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens is correct: Link-only answers are not considered answers on Stack Exchange. Answers need to be useful for future users too, not just for the user who asked the question, and an external link is not warranted to still be valid for all the time the question or the answer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the various modules already suggested in the other answers, I think you might also want to look at the [Scald: Media Management made easy](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald) module, which is more and more considered as an alternative to the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module.

Here is a quote about the Scald module (from its project page):

> ... a popular and flexible way to handle media in Drupal.
>
> Scald can handle images, video, audio, tweets and even Flash files. Scald works with YouTube, Vimeo, Soundcloud and other many other providers. You can see a full list on the scald provider's page, you can also read our FAQ.
>
> For end-users Scald is a great option because you can use Scald with popular editing tools such as CKEditor, and with Plupload for multiple file uploads. Scald also has a very user-friendly media library, based on Views.
>
> For developers, one of the best things about Scald is that it treats all files as full-blown fieldable entities.

And yes, it also has quite some [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1652740).